# How do I add csv file data into a dictionary

Tags: python, csv

me very new in programming, how do I make a dictionary that calls the Tour ID and displays the given info.(Tour, Start, End)

Tour = Tour Name

Start = Available reservations at the start

End = Amount of reservations left

csv file columns:

```
ID     |   Tour   | Start | End

12345  |  Italy   |  100  | 80

13579  |  China   |  50   | 30

24680  |  France  |  50   | 30
```

For example if I called the ID: "12345" it would display - Italy, 100, 80

Comment: "Make a library"? I assume you don't mean a python library?

Comment: A library? Usually one stores this into a database.

Comment: I meant a dictionary

Comment: have you tried using the python `csv` module? You might be interested in the [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: could you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, but making a dict is pretty easy.

```
d={
  '12345' : ['Italy',100,80],
 ....#add more as needed
}
```

Now d['12345'] will return that list with the info in it. Not sure what else you need...

Answer (score 1):

First let's create the file:

```
with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write("""\
ID,Tour,Start,End
12345,Italy,100,80
13579,China,50,30
24680,France,50,30""")
```

If you are going to work with Python and tables I recommend pandas. Here is a one-liner:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.read_csv("test.csv",sep=",").set_index('ID').to_dict(orient='i')
```

d returns

```
{12345: {'End': 80, 'Start': 100, 'Tour': 'Italy'},
 13579: {'End': 30, 'Start': 50, 'Tour': 'China'},
 24680: {'End': 30, 'Start': 50, 'Tour': 'France'}}
```

Or maybe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",sep=",").set_index('ID')
d = dict(zip(df.index,df.values.tolist()))
```

d returns

```
{12345: ['Italy', 100, 80],
 13579: ['China', 50, 30],
 24680: ['France', 50, 30]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import csv
data = list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv')))
final_data = {int(i[0]):[int(b) if b.isdigit() else b for b in i[1:]] for i in data}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
csv = """ID     |   Tour   | Start | End
12345  |  Italy   |  100  | 80
13579  |  China   |  50   | 30
24680  |  France  |  50   | 30"""

d = [[v.strip() for v in row.split('|')] for row in csv.split('\n')]
d = dict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in d)

print(d["12345"])
```